# putting values from an array into a hash with only keys

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Let's say I have an array of values such as `["Sonya", "New York", "America"]`. And then I have a hash with the keys only, such as `{name, state, country}`. How do I assign the values from the array to their respective keys in the hash? I know it's a loop, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What hash is `{name, state, country}`? Use real code to explain yourself.

Comment: Sonya, I suggest you edit to express the keys as an array whose elements are either strings or symbols; i.e., `["name", "state", "country"]` or `[:name, :state, :country]`. Also, when you give an example, it's always helpful to show your expected or desired result; e.g, `{ :name=>"Sonya", :state=>"New York", :country=>"America" }`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? It uses [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) to merge each element from `values` and `keys`, and then calls [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) to convert it to a `Hash`.

```
values = ["Sonya", "New York", "America"]
keys   = [:name, :state, :country]
hash   = keys.zip(values).to_h
# => {:name=>"Sonya", :state=>"New York", :country=>"America"}
```

Comment: You guys are fast! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A slight variant of @August's answer is:

```
[keys, values].transpose.to_h
  #=> {:name=>"Sonya", :state=>"New York", :country=>"America"}
```

or

```
Hash[[keys, values].transpose]
```

for Ruby versions prior to 2.0. Notice that `transpose` is the flip side of `zip`.